# How to Modify Active Form Field in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Normally, this code `<?= $form->field($model, 'q_36a')->checkbox() ?>` will produce the following...

```
<div class="form-group field-tblquestion-q_36a required">

<input type="hidden" name="TblQuestion[q_36a]" value="0"><label><input type="checkbox" id="tblquestion-q_36a" name="TblQuestion[q_36a]" value="1"> Q 36a</label>

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

how do i modify it to make it like this?

```
<label>
      <input name="switch-field-1" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-5" type="checkbox">
      <span class="lbl"></span>
</label>
```

I want to make it like this because I integrated ace admin template in my app.

Answer (score -1):

Got it working.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'q_36a', ['template' => "{input}<span class='lbl'></span>",])->checkbox(['class' => 'ace ace-switch ace-switch-5'], false) ?>
```